# Can I find Who or Which User uninstalled my app via clevertap.com?

Tags: android, clevertap

I wanted to find which user uninstalled app for some reason.I was searching for solution and got [this](https://support.clevertap.com/docs/understanding-app-uninstalled-event.html) clevertap.com. But I don't have clarity of wheather I can find User who uninstall it?

Comment: Go to the Uninstall Dashboard, select your desired date range, and see how many users uninstalled the app!!

Comment: I don't want count.I want User profile like they are showing in App Launch

Answer (score 0):

You can find out who uninstalled the App via Find People, where you can select "App Uninstalled" as the "Did Event [image: Find users who uninstalled App]

You'll see the users, and you can also download the list here

[image]

Ob disc: I'm the founder of [CleverTap](https://clevertap.com/)